# Google Play Billing Library v4 verification of in-app purchases

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-billing

I use Google Play Billing Library v4 for android app billing
(`implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"`)

I have not found any methods that can verify the purchase of a product by a user.
**If the user reinstalled the application, how can I check and restore all purchases in the application?**

All the options I found suggest me to use Google Play Developer API Method: *purchases.products.get*
**Does this always require a server?**
In any case, it seems to me difficult for a simple task.

I used this solution ([anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)), but this library is no longer supported and I decided to understand how billing works from Google in the latest version.

I would not like to use deprecated method `Purchase.PurchasesResult queryPurchases (String skuType)`
And this method I think will not help me `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync`

How can I simply implement a check of all my products (3), for the presence of payment by the user. If the user has reinstalled the application or changed the phone. I need to restore purchases to a user.

I am using Java.

Comment: This is no longer relevant with the release of a new version of the library from Google